# How do I loop through an array of hashes to get values of a nested array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, hash

I want to loop through and print out the values of the key "hobbies" one at a time

```
people = [
  {
    "first_name" => "Robert",
    "last_name" => "Garcia", 
    "hobbies" => ["basketball", "chess", "phone tag"]
   },
   {
    "first_name" => "Molly",
    "last_name" => "Barker",
    "hobbies" => ["programming", "reading", "jogging"]
   },
   {
    "first_name" => "Kelly",
    "last_name" => "Miller",
    "hobbies" => ["cricket", "baking", "stamp collecting"]
   }
]
```

This is as far as ive come up with before getting stumped

```
people.each { |inner|
    inner.each { |key, value|
      p value
    }
}
```

Comment: `people.map { |person| person["hobbies"] }` maps those hobbies to an array.

Comment: "not working" is not a precise enough problem description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```
people.each do |person|
  puts "- #{person['first_name']} #{person['last_name']}"
  person['hobbies'].each { |hobby| puts hobby }
end
```

Which would generate this output:

```
- Robert Garcia
basketball
chess
phone tag
- Molly Barker
programming
reading
jogging
- Kelly Miller
cricket
baking
stamp collecting
```